# sqlite3 update with inner join of another table

Tags: sqlite

I have a 2 table holiday and package.

holidayId has attribute of (holidayId,holidayName)

```
holidayId INTEGER Primary Key NOT NULL
holidayName varchar(45) NOT NULL
```

package

```
packageId INTEGER Primary Key NOT NULL
holidayId INT NOT NULL
endDate varchar(45) NOT NULL
FOREIGN KEY(holidayId) References Holiday(holidayId)
```

I want to update the value of endDate from package table matching against the value of holidayName in holiday table in sqlite3

meaning

If this is initial value

```
  Holiday table
  holidayName = "Package A";

  Package table
  endDate = "31-01-2014"
```

and I now I want to update the endDate value from "31-01-2014" to "30-01-2014",

- it will match against the holidayId in holiday table with the fk.holidayId in package table by using a inner join
- get the holidayName from holiday table and find the holidayName="package A".
- if holidayName="Package A" is found it will then update the endDate value.

I tried this

[image: sqlite3 update fail attempt]

Sorry if my explanation isn't clear as I don't really how to phrase my question and had tried my best to phrase it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could try:

```
UPDATE package 
SET endDate = '04-02-2014' 
WHERE holidayid in ( 
  SELECT holidayid 
  FROM Holiday
  WHERE holidayName = 'Package A'
) ;
```